# error C2065: 'CoInitializeEx' : undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, mfc

I get the following error while trying to use `hres =  CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);`

> error C2065: 'CoInitializeEx' : undeclared identifier

I have already included:

```
#define _WIN32_DCOM
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <comdef.h>
#include <Wbemidl.h>
```

in my cpp file.

Kindly help.

Thanks,
Neha

Answer (score 5):

Try placing the following line at the beginning of your precompiled header(*stdafx.h*).

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0400
```

Comment: Quick Google and found this - resolved my issue - I reckon this should be accepted as the answer.